# Having issues running ISO file on an HP Windows 10

Tags: bootloader, iso

I have Edubuntu loaded on to a USB and have already gone into BIOS and change the boot order to boot from the USB disk both from the main boot menu and the legend boot menu and it's still bypassing the disk and booting into Windows. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You cannot directly boot ISO, it must be extracted and DVD or flash drive converted to bootable. UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formated flash & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media If you want both UEFI & BIOS, has links to how to install: http://www.ubuntu.com/download and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick or: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb

Comment: Its already burned onto a usb and extracted and runs fine on my asus but won't work for my HP

Comment: So is it your install that does not boot on an HP? And then is it UEFI Windows? Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and if HP: Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789